# Public form with URL params

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm trying to create a public form ('controller/create/1'). The layout needs to be the same as whole page. What I get looks like Administration page.

```
function create($id){
    $this->layout = 'inner';
}
```

Once I set layout it requests all the stuff that is inside the layout template.

So how should I pass all required parameters of form? validations and so on, assuming the main missing parameter is the form HTML from the template file - rendered.

Answer (score 0):

there is an established convention where an controller action looks for a template file to be renderer. In your case cakephp looks for a template file `views/controller/create.ctp` - and there should your form code be written.

I suggest you start with the very nice blog tutorial here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Blog.html#adding-posts

You will find an example of how validation is done there as well.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Edited the post to include that version tag.